# C++ - Write images to PDF file

Tags: library, pdf, c++, images

Is there an easy to use PDF library (C++) to write a sequence of images to a PDF file?

Comment: which platform are you on? On Windows you don't need any libraries

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick CLI would be the easiest, you could trigger a shell execute from C++ using the OS C++ API, or maybe glib if you are on Linux.

Though there is also a C++ library for ImageMagick.

https://imagemagick.org/www/script/magick++.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [LEADTOOLS](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this library).

The following C++ code takes the name of any image file and saves the image into a PDF file. Subsequent calls to this function with different images will append the new images to the same file.

```
void AppendImageToPdf(TCHAR* pszInputImageName, TCHAR* pszOutputPDF)
{
   BITMAPHANDLE BmpPage = { 0 };
   L_LoadBitmap(pszInputImageName, &BmpPage, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 0, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);
   L_SaveFile(pszOutputPDF, &BmpPage, FILE_RAS_PDF_JPEG_411, 24, 25, SAVEFILE_MULTIPAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   L_FreeBitmap(&BmpPage);
}
```

There’s a free evaluation (with free tech support) [on this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main#main).